# How can I recover a partition table on external drive that has been destroyed by Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I recently reinstalled Windows and created a dual booting setup so that I can work on a project that required a Windows environment. I have an external drive that I thought I had formatted as FAT or exFAT. When I tried to open the drive from within Windows by double-clicking on it, the response seems much slower than usual (I didn't get the directory to open up). So, I rebooted into Ubuntu instead. I figured if there is an issue with accessing the files from within Windows, I can just access my files from within Ubuntu as I have always done.

To my surprise, I find that the drive is suddenly showing to be empty. Upon some investigation, it seems like the drive is showing approximately the amount of space that I expected to be used is still being used, and it seems the drive believes itself to have an NTFS partition now.

My tentative belief and hope are that Windows somehow automatically overwrote my partition table without asking when I merely tried to double click on the drive and that it did NOT do anything else.

I haven't used Windows for a while, so I wanted to ask those more familiar with Windows to see if this is the case. If so, it seems to me that this might be a fairly common problem, and I am hoping there is a common solution as well.

I haven't done much manual partition table creation and recovery. I also forgot the partition type I had on the drive before. I had assumed the partition was FAT/exFAT, but this experience clearly shows that it wasn't. Now, I can only assume that it was ext2/3/4. I am also fairly certain that I put all the space on the drive into a single partition, and didn't do anything fancy.

How can I attempt to recover the partition table and hence (hopefully) my files? Are there ways to experiment with trying to create a few different types of partition tables (maybe ext2/3/4, in turn, to see which one fits best) in a non-destructive way (if one partition table doesn't fit, it doesn't cause more damage)?

Comment: Windows doesn't so that. What do you mean by free/used space like you expect, where did you see that? Does the drive make any unusual noise?

Comment: If Windows overwrote the partitions then your data is gone.  This wouldn't have been done without user intervention.

Comment: The drive didn't make unusual noises. When I am in Ubuntu and have the drive plugged in, I can still use the GUI to ask about the drive properties. It's showing ~75% of the drive as used. However, when I open the drive, the GUI tells me it's empty and doesn't show any files. 

I just tried to query using commandline, I get a strange result when I just use `ls -al`:

`ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a failing drive or a drive with hardware faults - try to pull the data off the drive via [`testdisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and check the S.M.A.R.T data of the drive, running both a short and long test on the drive: `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>; smartctl -t short /dev/<disk>; sleep 120; smartctl -a /dev/<disk>; smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>` _(long test will take several hours and progress can be checked via `smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | grep progress` or `smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | findstr progress`)_; if that returns no errors, repair the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description the problem appears to be filesystem corruption. More specifically, at least the root directory is corrupted. If you want to back up your data, it is not that important where the corruption came from.

**It is important to not change anything on the drive anymore.** No tests either.

You should first create a backup image of the entire drive, using *ddrescue*. It's a Linux tool that specializes in backing up block storage that could have defective sectors. It will prioritize non-defective sectors first to rescue as much as possible.

This image will require as much space as the drive is in size. You may have to buy additional storage if you don't have enough free space. Ideally, you'd have twice as much, so you can create a working copy of the image. One to play with, one that remains unmodified.

Once you have backed up the data, you can attempt three things:

1. On Windows, using `chkdsk` against the drive (to maybe fix the corruption)
2. On Windows or Linux, using *PhotoRec* against the drive or the image (to maybe rescue the actual file data)
3. On Windows or Linux, using *TestDisk* to restore the MFT from its backup

Of course, if a hardware failure is to blame for the corruption, running `chkdsk` may only make things worse.

You could also remove the drive from its enclosure and mount it directly in your PC. USB enclosure electronics are often not so long-lived. When mounted internally, you can also reliably query SMART data and perform tests.

---

Because the system can mount the filesystem and even reports used space, it is clear that the partition table is 100% okay. The filesystem (or partition) type specified in the partition table is mostly irrelevant. You do not need to recover the partition table.